# Set new colors of pie slice on mouse hover using function till length of labels without giving new colors individually in list

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please provide a way so that instead of setting new colors manually I could give a single new color till the length of labels while mouse hover event takes place.

I have tried it using numpy library but it didn't worked. Have a look at the code:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
labels = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
sizes = [10, 35, 50, 5]
explode = (0, 0, 0.1, 0)  # only "explode" the 3rd slice (i.e. 'C')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
wedges, _, __ = ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, 
labels=labels,autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal') 

ocols= [w.get_facecolor() for w in wedges]
ncols= ["gold", "indigo", "purple", "salmon"]

def update(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax1:
        for i, w in enumerate(wedges):
            if w.contains_point([event.x, event.y]):
                w.set_facecolor(ncols[i])
            else:
                w.set_facecolor(ocols[i])
        fig1.canvas.draw_idle()


fig1.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", update)

plt.show()

ncols = ocols[np.where((ocols=='red').all(axis=2))]= ['grey']
```

I have tried this but an error is occuring stating :

```
ncols = ocols[np.where((ocols=='red').all(axis=2))]= ['grey']
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: I don't understand  *"give a single new color till the length of labels"*. Can you just state what should happen in each possible case?

Comment: Sir I am saying that while changing the colors of pie when mouse hover event takes place we place colors separtely as in above case it is ncols= ["gold", "indigo", "purple", "salmon"] . I want that existing colors should be replaced with a single color without passing that color in list again and again i.e it should not be like ncols=['grey','grey','grey','grey'] . What I want is that only once I should pass 'grey' color and it should iterate for all the slices of piechart. It will work fine when there would be more number of slices.

Comment: What about `ncols= ["grey"] * len(wedges)`?

Comment: Yes sir it worked perfectly fine. Thanks alot sir for your help.